Running SAI example returns SyntaxException, "no viable alternative at input 'OR'"
An error occurred when performing the OR operation according to cassandra's sai example
version：[cqlsh 6.2.0 | Cassandra 5.0-beta1 | CQL spec 3.4.7 | Native protocol v5]
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cycling.comments_vs (
      record_id timeuuid,
      id uuid,
      commenter text,
      comment text,
      comment_vector VECTOR <FLOAT, 5>,
      created_at timestamp,
      PRIMARY KEY (id, created_at)
    )
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC);
    CREATE INDEX commenter_idx
        ON cycling.comments_vs (commenter)
        USING 'sai';
    CREATE INDEX created_at_idx
        ON cycling.comments_vs (created_at)
        USING 'sai';
    CREATE INDEX ann_index
        ON cycling.comments_vs (comment_vector)
        USING 'sai';


    cqlsh> SELECT * FROM cycling.comments_vs
       ...     WHERE
       ...     created_at='2017-03-21 21:11:09.999000+0000'
       ...     OR created_at='2017-03-22 01:16:59.001000+0000';
    SyntaxException: line 4:4 no viable alternative at input 'OR' (...cycling.comments_vs    WHERE    created_at='2017-03-21 21:11:09.999000+0000'    [OR]...)

Why is the SELECT command giving that error?

The SELECT is throwing that exception on the OR operator. Functionality for the implementation of Storage Attached Indexes (SAI) has been split-out into version 1 and version 2. Support for the OR operator is in version 2, which is looking like we will see it in Cassandra 5.1.
